# Key inside Array won't parse correctly in TWIG

Tags: php, twig-extension

*testplugin.testplugin.firstkey* has following value *1, 2, 3*

I have follwing code written in TWIG:

```
{% set key1 = [config("testplugin.testplugin.firstkey")] %}

{% for ids in key1 %}
    {% set key1 = ids %}
    GO-{{ ids }} {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is, that the `config("testplugin.testplugin.firstkey")` won't get parsed correctly. Actually it only gets parsed as one value instead of 3 seperat values in an array. But when i define the values manually - without a variable - it works as it should:

```
{% set key2 = [1, 2, 3] %}

{% for ids in key2 %}
    {% set key2 = ids %}
    GO-{{ ids }} {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The first code does this:

```
GO-1, 2, 3
```

the second one looks like this (as it should):

```
GO-1, GO-2, GO-3
```

So my question is, why doeas the first code won't work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure it out by myself:

```
{% set key1 = config("testplugin.testplugin.firstkey"))|split(',') %}

{% for ids in key1 %}
    {% set key1 = ids %}
    GO-{{ ids }} {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks anyway ;-)